# Is something wrong with the review queues?

Tags: support, review

Thorsten Müller was presented with an [odd review question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/28155).  Odd, because the question was deleted on April 13, but he was asked today to review the first-post-answer in the deleted question.  Interestingly, MadKeithV was able to complete the review despite not seeing the question it pertained to.

[This is the deleted question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/63378/53019) and this is a link to the [answer to review](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/194562/53019).

This is a link to [The Whiteboard chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9158495#9158495) where Thorsten called out the oddity.

So is something borked in the review queues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was a [review audit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/review-audits/info):

> **Review audit passed 1 hour ago:**

Every so often you will be presented with a fake audit just to make sure you are paying attention. This was one of those times.

Everything is working as expected.

Comment: Seems weird that it would pull from a deleted question, but OK glad it can be declared working as expected.

Comment: @GlenH7 It is less of a problem here than it is for the Big Three, but some people will just quickly jump through the review queue to get the next badge as quick as possible.  The review audits on users help prevent that.